# Не могу понять в чём проблема при выборки числа из массива python

Tags: python

Прохожу тест от Yandex и там дано задание

> Дан массив a из n целых чисел. Напишите программу, которая найдет число, которое чаще других встречается в массиве.
>
> Формат ввода  В первой строке входных данных записано число n (1 ≤ n ≤
>   300 000). Во второй строке записаны n целых чисел ai (0 ≤ ai ≤
>   1 000 000 000).
>
> Формат вывода  Выведите единственное число x, наибольшее из чисел,
>   которое чаще других встречается в массиве a.

>

```html
Пример 1 

Ввод    Вывод 

3        3 
3 3 3 

Пример 2 
Ввод       Вывод 
5          4
4 1 4 3 3 


Пример 3 
Ввод                         Вывод 
10 
10 6 10 10 10 10 8 8 10 9     10
```

вот мой код :

```html
def mostFrequent(a, b): 
  
    a.sort() 
  
    
    max_count = 1; res = a[0]; curr_count = 1
      
    for i in range(1, b):  
        if (a[i] == a[i - 1]): 
            curr_count += 1
              
        else : 
            if (curr_count > max_count):  
                max_count = curr_count 
                res = a[i - 1] 
              
            curr_count = 1
      
    # If last element is most frequent 
    if (curr_count > max_count): 
      
        max_count = curr_count 
        res = a[b - 1] 
      
    return res 
  
# Driver Code 
n = int(input())
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
b = len(a) 

print(mostFrequent(a, b))
```

и когда например я ввожу :
n = 10 
a = 10 10 10 10 50 50 50 50 
То ответом выходит 50 , всё как в их задании , но всё время выдаёт ошибку " Неверный ответ " 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S Тест успешно завалил.Но всё интересно где я ошибся и как они хотели получить ответ.

Comment: Вы можете использовать Numpy/Pandas ?

Comment: Нет. только чистый python

Comment: а встроенные модули? Например `collections`?

Comment: Да можно его использовать

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так (сложность алгоритма `O(n)`):

```
def parse_input(s):
    return list(map(int, s.split()))

def mode_max(items):
    max_val = -1
    max_count = -1
    d = {}
    for i in items:
        d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
        if d[i] >= max_count:
            max_count = d[i]
            if i > max_val:
                 max_val = i                
    return max_val
```

---

тесты:

```
In [80]: mode_max(parse_input("10 6 10 10 10 10 8 8 10 9"))
Out[80]: 10

In [81]: mode_max(parse_input("10 10 10 10 50 50 50 50"))
Out[81]: 50
```

Comment: Не прошёл проверку и опять выдал ошибку : " ошибка в программе или неверный алгоритм"

Comment: из задачи В первой строке входных данных записано число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 300 000). Во второй строке записаны n целых чисел ai (0 ≤ ai ≤ 1 000 000 000).

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на это предложение в условии:

> Выведите единственное число x, **наибольшее из чисел**, которое чаще
>   других встречается в массиве a.

Если вы возьмёте второй пример из условия и введёте его в ваш код, то получите ответ 3. Но в примере ожидается ответ 4. В этом примере 3 и 4 встречаются одинаковое число раз (по два), но наибольшее из них - 4.

На вскидку кажется, что достаточно будет заменить в обоих условиях

```
if (curr_count > max_count):
```

знак "больше" на "больше или равно". Так как массив у вас отсортирован по возрастанию, то это гарантирует, что при равенстве счётчиков большее значение будет заменять меньшее. Сейчас же у вас наоборот - при равенстве счётчиков меньшее значение гарантированно сохранится.

Comment: Я исправил как  Вы предложили , теперь когда я запускаю код то получаю значения как в примере , но всё равно не проходит код , не нравится всё так же  алгоритм или сама программа

Answer (score 1):

```html
from collections import Counter
n = int(input()) 
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
c = Counter(a[0:n]).most_common()
max_inner = c[0][1]
c = [i[0] for i in c if i[1]==max_inner]
print(max(c))
```